# How to make Screen Transistion effect in blackberry application?

Tags: java, blackberry

I want to make slide transition effect in my blackberry application from navigating one screen to another screen.But when i collect information regarding this i can know that this effect only possible with 5.0 version.Is there any way to achieve this effect in lower version.

Answer (score 3):

I think the only way to do it is to take a screen shot of the 2 pages (one going out, one coming in) and use an extra 'transition' screen to move one in and one out.

Never tried it but I think that's the theory.

Comment: Yes, that's what I've heard as well

Comment: Fermin is correct, if you want to do screen transitions before 5.0, your best bet is to do your own animation.